# Strange error message: "Must declare the scalar variable" when pass TVP parameters into table-valued function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a simple custom type for use it as table valued parameter.
Like this:

```
 CREATE TYPE dbo.PeriodsList AS TABLE
    (
        PeriodDate NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
    )
```

I also have very simple table valued function:

```
alter FUNCTION GetPeriodsInYear (@periods  dbo.PeriodsList READONLY) returns @PeriodsSet Table(period NVARCHAR(8))

BEGIN
insert @PeriodsSet
select 
    '0' as period 
Return
end
```

But when I try to execute this function in this way

```
DECLARE @periods1 dbo.PeriodsList
INSERT INTO @periods1
VALUES ('20130916')

select * from GetPurchasesInYear(@periods1)
```

I receive error message - "Must declare the scalar variable "@periods1".
I have found many examples about stored procedures but not about functions. Is it possible to pass table valued parameters into functions?
And where the mistake in my code?

Comment: First, you got different 2 names here - GetPeriodsInYear and GetPurchasesInYear. Second, which line gives that error?

Comment: Is there any reason to pass a parameter to this function? You can simply get the result

select * from GetPeriodsInYear() because parameter is not used in the function.

Comment: I think I just copy my codes not in same time. Now I have the same function names in both parts of code but it is not work.
Whole warning message here: 
"Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Must declare the scalar variable "@periods1"."

For @dcp1986. Of course in this variant of function it is not need to use tvp parameters. But it is not finished function. This parameter will be need in future

Comment: What is the sql server you are using? This code works fine in my environment

Comment: "Select @@version" command receive following answer:
"Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64)   Sep 16 2010 19:43:16   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)"

Comment: can you try 

DECLARE @periods1 AS dbo.PeriodsList

Comment: Sorry but it is doesn't work also. But stored procedures work. I think I just avoid to use functions here.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "compatibility level" of your SQL Server 2008 database.  If it's set to 80 (SQL Server 2000), you will get the error you are describing when you try to call a function (but not a stored procedure) that takes a table-valued parameter.

It should work if the compatibility level value is 90 (SQL Server 2005) or higher.

To view the compatibility level of your database, do:

```
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'YOUR_DB_NAME_HERE';
```

Source: http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/pass-table-valued-para/97879

Changing the compatibility level (SQL Server 2008): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=sql.100%29.aspx